# A Makefile linker error

Tags: c, makefile

I have a problem that is causing me a headache, it is assumed that the command-L searches the libraries in the current directory of the Makefile, but it's not working for me, for example I have the following command in my Makefile:

```
...
LDLIBS  = -L/libs -lmatrix

main: main.o operations.o display.o
    $(CC) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@
...
```

And when I try to compile it literally says:

```
gcc  -L/libs -lmatrix main.o operations.o display.o -o main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmatrix
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

But when I simply change "-L/libs" for "-L$(PWD)/libs" it compiles perfectly and my program works fine...

But using "-L$(PWD)" I get another problem, if the name of any directory has a space It doesn't work again, actually I don't know if this problem is irremediable (using $(PWD) or not), but I still have the doubt that why it doesn't work without the $(PWD) because apparently (seeing **A LOT** of examples on the internet) using -L, the $(PWD) shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wrong that it's not needed.  The path `/libs` means the `libs` directory at the root of your filesystem.  Just like `/bin` doesn't mean "the `bin` directory under my current directory", so `/libs` doesn't mean the `libs` directory under the current directory.

If you want to look in `libs` in the current directory, just use `-Llibs` or if you want to be more specific, `-L./libs` (the directory `.` is the current directory, so `cd .` changes to the current directory, just like `cd ..` changes to the parent directory).

Comment: it's also a good idea to shift all the linker-related options to the end of the command line, after the name of your output, in this case after `-o main` .

Answer (score 1):

The path **/PATHNAME** means the directory at the root of your filesystem. If you want to use  $(PWD) for your current directory then you can quote the shell variables like: **"$(PWD)"**. Do not escape the quotes.